# Go api working on colleague's computer, endpoints returning 404 on mine?

Tags: api, go, endpoint

I'm building a basic API in Go, and after my code working perfectly earlier today, my endpoints are all returning 404s. I have a basic handler function below to illustrate.

Someone else on my team was able to run this code successfully, so I don't think it's the actual code. I'm concerned there is something about my computer or browser environment that are causing the 404s (or I made a stupid mistake). All of the imports are for the rest of the api functionality.

The two print lines telling me the database connection & server is running, so the program itself is running, but the endpoints are all returning 404s after working correctly this morning.

What can I look into or try here?

I've restarted my computer, cleared my browser cache, restarted the server a bunch, etc. Any version of turn it off and on again that I could think of has been tried.

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"

    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "github.com/joho/godotenv"
)

var port = "8080"
var db *sql.DB
var host string

func main() {
    // Getting environment variables that are secret
    host = "localhost:8080"

    err := godotenv.Load("week2.env")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error loading .env file")
    }
    // Connecting to the MySQL database
    pw, _ := os.LookupEnv("MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD")
    user, _ := os.LookupEnv("MYSQL_USER")
    ds := fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s@tcp(db:3306)/google_books", user, pw)
    database, err := sql.Open("mysql", ds)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("successfully connected to db")
    db = database
    defer db.Close()
    // Setting up a mux router
    router := mux.NewRouter()

    // Telling the server what to listen for and what to do
    router.HandleFunc("/", hello)

    // Creating the server
    fmt.Printf("listening on port %s\n", port)
    err = http.ListenAndServe(":"+port, router)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}
func hello(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    setHeaders(w, r)
    fmt.Println("hello world this is the homepage")
}

// setHeaders sets the headers for the response
func setHeaders(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the information you provided, I will have to guess a little.

Your `404` error could be related to a database error.
When you run `database, err := sql.Open("mysql", ds)`, you are opening a connection, but not necessarily authenticating yet.

Add a ping below the `sql.Open` line to test it, like this:

```
err = db.Ping()
if err != nil{
    log.Fatalf("%s", err)
}
```

Also, in you request, make sure you add more information to the response body so you know exactly where the 404 was generated.